# Best place to display filter button in mobile

Tags: tables, filter, data-tables, conventions

I'm currently designing a screen for mobile with a navigation bar and a filter button. However, I'm at a loss about what the best placement for the filter button is.

This is my current screen:

[image: screen with a centred title "Actividades" and a menu button to the left of the title. Below the menu button there is a filter button labelled "Filtrar".]

However I don't think the button is accessible enough, as the user might tap the menu button accidentally due to proximity. Another issue is whether I should show the current filters on the table screen, or just show the current state on the filter's pop-up window? In case I should, where is the best place for the current filter information?

Comment: Better to place a filter icon at the top of the header as a user can easily accessable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not put the filters in the top right of the navbar and then add the current state of the filters where you have the button now?

[image: plain navbar with filter option]